converting dip::Image to QImage
I want to use DIPlip library for my project in Qt framework to show the result of DIPlib Image I need to convert dip::Image class to Qt framework QImage class, in format QImage::Format_RGB888.
How can I convert DIPlib dip::Image to QImage for grey Image in C++ language?

I haven't used any of them them, but according to the dip::Image documentation you can access the raw data (with Data()), as well as the width,height etc., and QImage has constructors that accepts this info to create a QImage object. Note that the data buffer from dip::Image should remain valid as long as the QImage is alive. You can clone it if needed.

Which Qt format do you want the image to be? There are lots, and each would require a different step to coerce the data into the right format. Some formats are compatible with DIPlib, some are not. The ones that are not would require you write some more complex conversion code. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qimage.html#Format-enum

@CrisLuengo I want to use QImage::Format_RGB888 format

Qt's QImage::Format_RGB888 is storage-compatible with DIPlib, as far as I can tell from its documentation. The main difference is that it expects each scanline (row) to be 32-bit aligned. So, depending on the width of the image, there might be between 1 and 3 bytes of padding at the end of each line. DIPlib does not do this by default, and it is not trivial to get it to do so in all cases (it is easy for the gray-scale case, but not for the RGB case).
So the best approach is to have Qt allocate the image data, encapsulate that in a dip::Image object, and write to that.
You need to make sure that you keep the Qt object alive while you use the DIPlib one. The Qt object owns the data.
In most cases, Qt image data has some padding at the end of each line, so we need to explicitly tell DIPlib about the strides (size of a step to get to the next pixel along each dimension). We use this dip::Image constructor:
int width = 800;
int height = 600;
QImage qt_image(width, height, QImage::Format::Format_RGB888);

dip::Image dip_image(
    dip::NonOwnedRefToDataSegment(qt_image.constBits()),
    const_cast<uchar*>(qt_image.constBits()),
    dip::DT_UINT8,
    {qt_image.width(), qt_image.height()}, 
    {3, qt_image.bytesPerLine()}, 
    dip::Tensor{3},
    1
);
dip_image.Protect();  // prevents the image from being reallocated

You can now write into dip_image with any DIPlib function (as long as they accept 3-channel output), and qt_image will be updated as well.

You can do the same thing with some of the other formats (RGBA64, RGB32, RGBX32FPx4, etc.), but the formats where multiple sample values are packed into fewer bytes (such as RGB16 or RGB666) need to be converted to a different format first (and consequently DIPlib cannot write into those).

Formats where each pixel takes up 32 bits or a multiple (RGBA64, RGB32, RGBX32FPx4) will not need any padding. In this case you can use the simplified dip::Image constructor (documentation):
dip::Image dip_image(const_cast<uchar*>(qt_image.constBits()), {qt_image.width(), qt_image.height()}, 3);
dip_image.Protect();  // prevents the image from being reallocated


For this case, where there is no padding, we can also create a DIPlib image object and encapsulate that in a Qt object. QImage has a constructor (documentation) that takes a pointer to the pixel data and the sizes and format as input:
dip::Image dip_image({padded, height}, 4, dip::DT_UINT8);

QImage::QImage qt_image(static_cast<uchar*>(dip_image.Origin()), dip_image.Size(0), dip_image.Size(1), QImage::Format::Format_RGB32);

You can now display qt_image, and the user will see the image in dip_image. Modifying either will modify the other too, as they're sharing data.
If dip_image is modified with methods such as Mirror() or Rotation90(), then its layout no longer matches what Qt expects. Use dip_image.ForceNormalStrides() to rewrite the data in the standard format (note that there will be no padding after this, so that doesn't work for RGB888).

DIPlib also supports automatically allocating a Qt image whenever a DIPlib image is reforged. This is done through dip::ExternalInterface. There are some examples available if you want to go this route. It's not trivial to write an external interface for Qt, but once you've written it, it will be really easy to use.

For your specific use case:
dip::String fname = "2.jpg";
auto info = dip::ImageReadJPEGInfo(fname);
QImage qt_image(info.sizes[0], info.sizes[1], QImage::Format::Format_RGB888);
dip::Image dip_image(
    dip::NonOwnedRefToDataSegment(qt_image.constBits()),
    const_cast<uchar*>(qt_image.constBits()),
    dip::DT_UINT8,
    info.sizes,
    {3, qt_image.bytesPerLine()},
    dip::Tensor{3},
    1
);
dip_image.Protect();
if (info.tensorElements == 1) {
    dip::Image channel = dip_image[0];
    dip::ImageReadJPEG(channel, fname);
    dip_image[1] = channel;
    dip_image[2] = channel;
} else {
    dip::ImageReadJPEG(dip_image, fname);
}


I try to use Encapsulating grey color  dip::Image data in a QImage object. it didn't work properly when I  show the Image on the screen image is crooked and repeats itself several times but When I use colored dip::image it works perfectly

@AhmetManyasli The data has to match. For Format_RGB888, the DIPlib image obviously needs to have 3 channels and be DT_UINT8, as in the example I gave. If the format doesn't match, you must first make it match.

@AhmetManyasli I missed a detail about scanline alignment, see the updated answer. This is most likely the distortion you're seeing. Note that you can do dip::Image img = dip::JoinChannels({img1, img1, img1}); to turn a grayscale into an RGB image. You can also use dip::ColorSpaceManager for that, but it's a bit more involved.

I updated my code according to your edited answer, now the image is not crooked or distorted but I can see 2/3 of the height of the image on the screen. The dimensions of the image I am trying to display are 951(width)x751(height). Interestingly, when I try to display an image with dimensions of 1122(width)x742(height), the image appears crooked on the screen.

My updated code is below dip::Image img1 = dip::ImageReadJPEG("2.jpg"); dip::uint width = img1.Size(0);dip::uint height = img1.Size(1); dip::uint padded_width = dip::div_ceil(width, (dip::uint)4) * 4; dip::Image dip_image({padded_width, height}, 3, dip::DT_UINT8); dip_image.Crop({width, height}, "top left");dip_image.Protect(); dip_image = dip::JoinChannels({img1, img1, img1}); QImage qt_image(static_cast<uchar*>(dip_image.Origin()), dip_image.Size(0), dip_image.Size(1), QImage::Format::Format_RGB888); ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qt_image));

@AhmetManyasli Does it work?

No it is not working some images is not distorted but 1/3 of image is missing from bottom of image or some images distorted

@AhmetManyasli I don't see why it wouldn't work. Maybe there's some other weird thing about how Qt stores its images that is not apparent from the documentation. Is img1 in your code really a scalar (single channel) image? ---- One unrelated thing: instead of dip_image = dip::JoinChannels({img1, img1, img1}) you can do dip::JoinChannels({img1, img1, img1}, dip_image), it saves a copy. Most functions in DIPlib can take an out image to write into.

@AhmetManyasli I see now what the problem was. The line length is not width, but width*3, that is what needs to be padded. There is no trivial way to do this in DIPlib without writing a custom allocator (it can be done, but the alternative is much easier). So, instead, have Qt allocate the image, and encapsulate that in DIPlib. See the code at the bottom of the post for my rewrite of your code. I haven't compiled it (have never used Qt), but it should be more or less correct.

When I use alternative solution compiler gives  "No matching constructor for initialization of 'dip::Image'"  error

@AhmetManyasli I've installed Qt, and insured it compiles. I had to make two small changes to ensure proper types.
